# Remove linebreaks when using {{each}}

Tags: markdown, handlebars.js, semantic-release

I have the following handlebars template to generate a changelog.md with gitmoji:

```
#  {{nextRelease.version}}

{{#with commits}}
{{#if sparkles}}
## ✨ New Features
{{#each sparkles}}
- {{> commitTemplate}}
{{/each}}
{{/if}}
{{/with}}
```

when the changelog is generated I get results like this (in markdown):

```
#  19.15.0

## ✨ New Features
-  first feature commit

-  second feature commit

-  third feature commit
```

while this visually does not affect the markdown result, I feel that the readability can be a little messy or atleast maybe this is just personal preference, but I would like to get the following result (**remove the linebreaks between each feature**):

```
#  19.15.0

## ✨ New Features
-  first feature commit
-  second feature commit
-  third feature commit
```

I had been searching and found about this documentation: https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#whitespace-control

So I tried like this:

```
{{~#each sparkles}}
- {{> commitTemplate}}
{{~/each}}
```

but this gave me the following wrong result:

```
#  19.15.0

## ✨ New Features-  first feature commit
-  second feature commit
-  third feature commit
```

Also other ways I tried but did not work were:

```
## ✨ New Features<br>
{{~#each sparkles}}
- {{> commitTemplate}}
{{~/each}}
```

and:

```
## ✨ New Features

{{~#each sparkles}}
- {{> commitTemplate}}
{{~/each}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[White-space control](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#whitespace-control) is how you should be handling this.

Note that you can include the `~` character on *either the left or right side* of your handlebars expression and they don't have to be "balanced" at all. You can include a `~` in a closing expression and not its opening.

It is a little hard to replicate since it isn't entirely clear what your `commitTemplate` partial looks like, but my guess is you only need to remove whitespace before the closing `{{/each}}`, so your full code would look like

```
#  {{nextRelease.version}}

{{#with commits}}
{{#if sparkles}}
## ✨ New Features
{{#each sparkles}}
- {{> commitTemplate}}
{{~/each}}
{{/if}}
{{/with}}
```

[Handlebars playground link](https://handlebarsjs.com/playground.html#format=1&currentExample=%7B%22template%22%3A%22%23%20%F0%9F%8E%89%20%7B%7BnextRelease.version%7D%7D%5Cn%5Cn%7B%7B%23with%20commits%7D%7D%5Cn%7B%7B%23if%20sparkles%7D%7D%5Cn%23%23%20%E2%9C%A8%20New%20Features%5Cn%7B%7B%23each%20sparkles%7D%7D%5Cn-%20%7B%7B%3E%20commitTemplate%7D%7D%5Cn%7B%7B%7E%2Feach%7D%7D%5Cn%7B%7B!%20%F0%9F%91%86%20I%20only%20include%20whitespace%20control%20in%20your%20closing%20%27each%27%7D%7D%5Cn%7B%7B%2Fif%7D%7D%5Cn%7B%7B%2Fwith%7D%7D%22%2C%22partials%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22commitTemplate%22%2C%22content%22%3A%22%7B%7Bthis%7D%7D%5Cn%7B%7B!%20Does%20your%20partial%20have%20a%20line%20break%3F%20%7D%7D%22%7D%5D%2C%22input%22%3A%22%7B%5Cn%20%20nextRelease%3A%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20version%3A%20%5C%221.0.0%5C%22%5Cn%20%20%7D%2C%5Cn%20%20commits%3A%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20sparkles%3A%20%5B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22hello%5C%22%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22world%5C%22%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22foo%5C%22%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22bar%5C%22%5Cn%20%20%20%20%5D%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%5Cn%22%2C%22output%22%3A%22%23%20%F0%9F%8E%89%201.0.0%5Cn%5Cn%23%23%20%E2%9C%A8%20New%20Features%5Cn-%20hello%5Cn-%20world%5Cn-%20foo%5Cn-%20bar%5Cn%22%2C%22preparationScript%22%3A%22%5Cn%22%2C%22handlebarsVersion%22%3A%224.7.8%22%7D).